# JAXB returns null for element mapped to Date type

Tags: java, xml, datetime, jaxb

I have a little problem with jaxb unmarshalling.

I have this piece of xml:

```
<item>
    <title>My title</title>
    <link>https://some-link/</link>
    <comments>Hello world</comments>
    <pubDate>Thu, 13 Jan 2016 09:45:06 +0000</pubDate>
</item>
```

One item is represented as Item class in java code:

```
@XmlType
public class Item{

    private String title;

    //link and comments I'm temporary skipping

    @XmlElement(name = "pubDate")
    private Date publicDate;

    //getters and setters
}
```

So, when I'm trying to unmarshall this xml, I've got `publicDate` equals null. 
What I do wrong? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let JAXB know that you are annotating directly on the private field:

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item{

    private String title;

    //link and comments I'm temporary skipping

    @XmlElement(name = "pubDate")
    private Date publicDate;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Alternatively, you can leave out the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation altogether and annotate the getter for `publicDate` instead. The default behavior for `@XmlAccessorType` is to bind every public field and/or public getter/setter.

Comment: Even when I annotate class with @XmlAccessorType or add annotation on publicDate getter it still returns null

Answer (score 0):

JAXB will only let you to automatically unmarshall to a java.util.Date instance if the date format matches the xsd type dateTime: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`; but the format in your sample xml is different and in that case you'll need to implement your own helper implementing `XmlAdapter<String,Date>`, like the following:

```
public class MyDateFormatAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private static final String FORMAT = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";

    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT);
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }

}
```

Demo here: http://ideone.com/0dngV3

Comment: I've checked. This code also returs pubDate equals null

Comment: If I set datetime in xml like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss format then everything works...

Comment: The code I posted does NOT return null, in facts the link at the bottom of the answer, proves it is working  fine. check your code better.

Comment: Yes, it works at my work's pc, but unfortenatly it doesn't work on my laptop. And I can't figure out why. It seems that, environments are the same (windows 7, jdk 1.7) on both computers.
I've raised one more issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701854/one-java-code-behave-differ-on-2-differ-pc