# one java code behave differ on 2 differ pc

Tags: java, jaxb, java-7, environment

I have simple JAXB unmarshalling code.

```
package com.example;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
        xml.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
            .append("<item><pubDate>Thu, 12 May 2016 08:44:05 +0000</pubDate></item>");

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(new StringReader( xml.toString()));
        Item example = (Item) jaxbMarshaller.unmarshal(ss);
        System.out.println(example);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

Item class:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Item {

    @XmlElement(name = "pubDate")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyDateFormatAdapter.class)
    private Date pubDate;

    public String toString() {
        return "Item:"+this.pubDate.toString();
    }

    public Date getPubDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public void setPubDate(Date pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }


}
```

and MyDateFormatAdapter class

```
package com.example;


import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MyDateFormatAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private static final String FORMAT = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";

    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT);
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }

    public String marshal(Date d) throws Exception { 
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT);
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(d);
        return formattedDate; 

    }

}
```

So, on the first pc(windows 7, jdk 1.7) code fails with NullPointerException at line `System.out.println(example);` on the second pc(windows 7, jdk 1.7) it work ok. Returns `Item:Thu May 12 10:44:05 CEST 2016`
I can't figure out what is the reason of such behavior. Maybe some assumption?

UPDATED:
When I'm removing annotation `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyDateFormatAdapter.class)` the code become work as on laptop and throws the same exceptions

```
 exception java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.Item.toString(Item.java:21)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2849)
        at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
        at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Do you really get a NPE at `System.out.println(example);`? Did you tripple check you're running the correct code on that machine and that the error corresponds in that line? The only thing in that line which I could think of producing a NPE would be `out`, i.e. if there is no output stream available.

Comment: Please be _specific_ on where you get that NPE, ideally post the stacktrace here. Do you _really_ get it in `System.out.println(example);`or is it thrown in `Item#toString()`?

Comment: Just for future questions: you should have mentioned right from the start that you got the NPE at `Item.toString()`. Telling us a different location that calls the code is only slightly better than "somewhere in the program" (which would be equivalent to "in `main()`").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyDateFormatAdapter` depends on the default platform locale of the JVM.

If that locale is not an english locale it will not be able to parse `Thu` for date pattern `EEE`.
In this case `dateFormat.parse` will throw a `ParseException`. The Unmarshaller catches that exception but then the `pubDate` member will be initialized to null.

As a consequence your `Item.toString` raises a NPE since it relies on a non null `pubDate` value.

Solution: Specify a locale when you create the DateFormat.

```
public class MyDateFormatAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);

    @Override public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }

    @Override public String marshal(Date d) throws Exception { 
        return dateFormat.format(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally if the locale is not English then `May` will probably not be recognized either. That's another example why those string interpretation methods (like parsing, reading from streams etc.) that take system settings as their default are somewhat a pain in the ass. It's easy to use them and thus easy to produce errors that inexperienced devs have a hard time to track down or explain. +1 anyways and if I could I'd give you another for "Specify a locale when you create the DateFormat".